# Find XPath of Text which is Under Div Tag and besides span tag

Tags: html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver, domxpath

Sorry if this is discussed before. I tried searching it but didn't find exact match. My question is I have low HTML code,

```
<div class="column1">
<div>
<div class="name">
Dynamic Name
<span class="id" title="ID">Dynamic ID</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am looking for XPath to get text Dynamic Name.
Here is what I tried which didn't work

```
1. //div/div[@class='name'] which is finding text Dynamic Name Dynamic ID

2. //div/span[@class='id']/preceding-sibling::text()
```

Since Dynamic Name & Dynamic ID, both are the dynamic value, I can't use split & use name as we don't know where to split it.
Thanks in advance for your time & help.

Comment: You say the name and id values are dynamic, yet you use them in your XPath attempts.  Which is it?   Can you rely on their values or not?  If not, what's invariant?  You can't expect us to figure that out from your sketchy description and single example.

Comment: Sorry plz refresh page. I just updated.

Comment: I want to find Xpath to use get Dynamic Name Only (without appending Dynamic ID).

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(//div[@class="name"]/text())
```

will return `"Dynamic Name"` for your HTML, as requested.

---

> Thanks but it has some syntax error as i tried putting on Firepath and its giving some error. not sure which one.

Wild guess: See if

```
//div[@class="name"]/text()
```

avoids your syntax error (which would be a limitation of your tool as `normalize-space()` is a proper XPath 1.0 function) and selects your targeted text (although with extraneous whitespace).

Comment: Thanks but it has some syntax error as i tried putting on Firepath and its giving some error. not sure which one.

Comment: You'll have to say what the error is if you want help with it.  The XPath I've provided is syntactically correct and does work against the HTML in your question.

Comment: Not sure. I tried it to get text but I am getting Exception as Element not found for xpath By.xpath: normalize-space(//div[@class='name']/text())

Comment: Try without `normalize-space()`.  If that works, your XPath processor is broken.  If that fails too, then your posted HTML is not your actual HTML.

Comment: //div[@class="name"]/text() is throwing the same Element not found exception.

Comment: **Then your posted HTML is not your actual HTML, or you're calling the wrong XPath library call, or something else that's not reflected in your question is wrong.**

Comment: <div class="recordset_frame">
    <script id="member_recordset_template" type="text/html"/>
    <div id="member_recordset" class="recordset">
    <div class="control" style="display: block;">
    <div class="records">
    <div class="record">
    <div class="column1">
    <div>
    <div class="name">
    StaffTest1, Selenium
    <span class="id" title="ID">6001</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Comment: above is the code i copied and pasted here. its original. I understand its tough and i am using different workaound as i am not able to find "Name value" alone. If u find solution, plz post here, else Thank You for your time

Comment: Add your actual call to an XPath processor to your question.  I'm beginning to suspect that you're calling a function that's expecting to select an *element* because you write that `//div/div[@class='name']`  *is finding text `Dynamic Name Dynamic ID 2`* and yet say that  `//div/div[@class='name']/text()` is throwing an element-not-found exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that the XPath `//div/div[@class='name']` is working but returns too much info, we can grab that element, grab the `innerHTML`, and then split on the first `<`, take the first `String`, and `trim()` it just in case to get the answer.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div[@class='name']")).getAttribute("innerHTML").split("<")[0].trim();
```